# How can I link functions in a Sphinx table?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, documentation-generation, read-the-docs

I have added functions to the "Usage" section of my Read the Docs project which I am designing with Sphinx. I'm looking for a way that I can automatically link each function in a table or chart, preferably an attribute table.

Being familiar with [discord.py](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py) and its [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io), I have been using it to figure out the best way to structure my own documentation. The documentation's [API Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html) contains attribute tables with a list of attributes and methods. See the image below:

[Discord.py API Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC5Lf.png)

The "Usage" page of my Read The Docs project contains `.. function::`'s under a title. Is there an extension or tag I can use in order to have all the functions in that heading combined into an attribute table?

If there isn't, I am flexible with linking each function in a basic Sphinx table with Attributes and Parameters. Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: The discord.py documentation uses a custom Sphinx directive called "attributetable": https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/docs/extensions/attributetable.py

Comment: As mzjn said, you need to use the custom Sphinx extension "attributetable". I will supplement his answer. From the same folder with extensions, you also need an extension builder.py. If you do everything right, everything will work. If you also want to connect css styles so that everything is displayed as beautifully as in the discord documentation, you can find them in the docs/_static/style.css folder in the same repository. Good luck! :)